# How can i plot a Kmeans text clustering result with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following code to cluster some example text with scikit learn.

```
train = ["is this good?", "this is bad", "some other text here", "i am hero", "blue jeans", "red carpet", "red dog", "blue sweater", "red hat", "kitty blue"]

vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(train)
clf = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
clf.fit(X)
centroids = clf.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], marker='x', s=80, linewidths=5)
plt.show()
```

The thing i cant figure out is how i can plot the clustered results. X is a csr_matrix. What i want is (x, y) coord for each result to plot.

Ty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your tf-idf matrix ends up being 3 x 17, so you need to do some sort of projection or dimensionality reduction to get centroids in two dimensions. You have several options; here's an example with t-SNE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

train = ["is this good?", "this is bad", "some other text here", "i am hero", "blue jeans", "red carpet", "red dog",
     "blue sweater", "red hat", "kitty blue"]

vect = TfidfVectorizer()  
X = vect.fit_transform(train)
random_state = 1
clf = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state = random_state)
data = clf.fit(X)
centroids = clf.cluster_centers_

tsne_init = 'pca'  # could also be 'random'
tsne_perplexity = 20.0
tsne_early_exaggeration = 4.0
tsne_learning_rate = 1000
model = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=random_state, init=tsne_init, perplexity=tsne_perplexity,
         early_exaggeration=tsne_early_exaggeration, learning_rate=tsne_learning_rate)

transformed_centroids = model.fit_transform(centroids)
print transformed_centroids
plt.scatter(transformed_centroids[:, 0], transformed_centroids[:, 1], marker='x')
plt.show()
```

In your example if you use PCA to initialize your t-SNE you get widely spaced centroids; if you use random initialization you'll get tiny centroids and an uninteresting picture.

Comment: I wonder if this is also possible to print (on the same scatter) the corresponding documents in the corpus that are close to each centroid? @Mike Delong

Comment: @AndreaMoro Yes it looks like this is possible. The t-SNE model doesn't have separate fit and transform methods; if it did we could fit on the original data X and transform both the original data and the centroids and just plot them together with different markers. So instead we need to get the centroids out of the k-means model, concatenate them together with X, then pass the whole thing together through the t-SNE model and then plot the X rows and the centroids rows separately. It looks like the t-SNE model preserves row order, so this is pretty simple.

Comment: thanks. Not sure I understand the concatenation part. Wouldn't this mix the information? Perhaps you can amend your answer to cover this too?

Comment: @AndreaMoro please see below.

Comment: Thanks. Last one. A perplexity that arose while using a different approach based on sklearn.decomposition. However, I noticed that reducing dimensionality there required also to refit the model, and the clusterization was later different. I'm now in doubt whether this is correct, considering that this reduction is - at least in my case - done just for the sake of plotting.

Comment: @AndreaMoro you should be able to get repeatable results by using the random state parameter. I have edited my original answer to introduce the random state into both the k-means and t-SNE models.

Comment: The random state is always there in my test just to avoid problem. I would assume the problem was in using the sklearn package? I have plaid around and posted another question here with some bits of code if you have some time: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/79628/how-to-plot-centroids-and-clusters-resulting-from-a-kmean-model-based-on-a-text

Answer (score 4):

Here is a longer, better answer with more data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import concatenate
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE

train = [
    'In 1917 a German Navy flight crashed at/near Off western Denmark with 18 aboard',
    # 'There were 18 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1942 a Deutsche Lufthansa flight crashed at an unknown location with 4 aboard',
    # 'There were 4 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1946 Trans Luxury Airlines flight 878 crashed at/near Moline, Illinois with 25 aboard',
    # 'There were 2 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1947 a Slick Airways flight crashed at/near Hanksville, Utah with 3 aboard',
    'There were 3 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1949 a Royal Canadian Air Force flight crashed at/near Near Bigstone Lake, Manitoba with 21 aboard',
    'There were 21 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1952 a Airwork flight crashed at/near Off Trapani, Italy with 57 aboard',
    'There were 7 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1963 a Aeroflot flight crashed at/near Near Leningrad, Russia with 52 aboard',
    'In 1966 a Alaska Coastal Airlines flight crashed at/near Near Juneau, Alaska with 9 aboard',
    'There were 9 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1986 a Air Taxi flight crashed at/near Frenchglen, Oregon with 6 aboard',
    'There were 3 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1989 a Air Taxi flight crashed at/near Gold Beach, Oregon with 3 aboard',
    'There were 18 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1990 a Republic of China Air Force flight crashed at/near Yunlin, Taiwan with 18 aboard',
    'There were 10 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1992 a Servicios Aereos Santa Ana flight crashed at/near Colorado, Bolivia with 10 aboard',
    'There were 44 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1994 Royal Air Maroc flight 630 crashed at/near Near Agadir, Morocco with 44 aboard',
    'There were 10 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1995 Atlantic Southeast Airlines flight 529 crashed at/near Near Carrollton, GA with 29 aboard',
    'There were 44 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 1998 a Lumbini Airways flight crashed at/near Near Ghorepani, Nepal with 18 aboard',
    'There were 18 passenger/crew fatalities',
    'In 2004 a Venezuelan Air Force flight crashed at/near Near Maracay, Venezuela with 25 aboard',
    'There were 25 passenger/crew fatalities',
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
n_clusters = 2
random_state = 1
clf = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=random_state)
data = clf.fit(X)
centroids = clf.cluster_centers_
# we want to transform the rows and the centroids
everything = concatenate((X.todense(), centroids))

tsne_init = 'pca'  # could also be 'random'
tsne_perplexity = 20.0
tsne_early_exaggeration = 4.0
tsne_learning_rate = 10
model = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=random_state, init=tsne_init,
    perplexity=tsne_perplexity,
    early_exaggeration=tsne_early_exaggeration, learning_rate=tsne_learning_rate)

transformed_everything = model.fit_transform(everything)
print(transformed_everything)
plt.scatter(transformed_everything[:-n_clusters, 0], transformed_everything[:-n_clusters, 1], marker='x')
plt.scatter(transformed_everything[-n_clusters:, 0], transformed_everything[-n_clusters:, 1], marker='o')

plt.show()
```

There are two clear clusters in the data: one is a description of the crash, the other is a summary of the fatalities. It is easy to comment out lines and tune the cluster sizes up and down a little. As written the code should show two blue clusters, one larger and one smaller, with two orange centroids. There are more items of data than there are markers: some of the rows of data are transformed onto identical points in space.

[image: two clusters]
Finally, a smaller t-SNE learning rate seems to produce tighter clusters.

Comment: I have 18 clusters and I would like to make use of the example above. Will this work for my use case or do you suggest any changes?. @Mike DeLong